# replace string comprising specific text + changing pattern in r

Tags: regex, r, str-replace

I'm trying to remove a specific pattern followed by changing combination of digits or letters in an R script.

Pattern to be removed:
" **Alpha code for WIS - Info Only - see journal XXXX**"

where XXXX can be a 4-digit number, a combination of a letter + 3-digit number or 3 letters.

I've tried already:

```
str_replace(x, '^\\s "Alpha code for WIS - Info Only - see journal" \\b[A-Z1-9]{4}\\b','') 

str_replace(x, '^\\s "Alpha code for WIS - Info Only - see journal" ([0-9])','')  

str_replace(x, '^\\sAlpha code for WIS - Info Only - see journal ([0-9]+)','')
```

None of these work. 
I've also tried similar regex with gsub, and again I didn't go any further.

I could go in 3 steps, replacing first the 4-digit number, then the letter combination and finally the alphanumeric, if it's easier.

Comment: Please include at least one example with expected output. For example, in string A I would like output A returned.

Comment: `'\\sAlpha code for WIS - Info Only - see journal (\\d{4}|\\w\\d{3}|\\w{3})'`, I believe...

Comment: I'm suggesting for you to try some online regex-sandboxes. They prove helpfull...

Comment: @ankhzet thnx, i didn't know about them.

Comment: @pierre-lafortune i want to remove completely all matching strings. i.e. "journal sth Alpha code for WIS - Info Only - see journal E345" becomes "journal sth"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a regex like this with `gsub`:

```
"Alpha code for WIS - Info Only - see journal ([0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}|[a-zA-Z]{3})
```

So the snippet of code will be:

```
test <- "Line1: Alpha code for WIS - Info Only - see journal 1234\nLine2: Alpha code for WIS - Info Only - see journal A123\nLine3: Alpha code for WIS - Info Only - see journal AbC\nLine4: line 4 content"
result <- gsub("Alpha code for WIS - Info Only - see journal ([0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}|[a-zA-Z]{3})", '', test)
print(result)
```

**Output**

> [1] "Line1: \nLine2: \nLine3: \nLine4: line 4 content"